# How this multi-threaded socket server program working?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, sockets

So I was exploring threading and socket server in python 3. And I am stuck with a weird thing which I can't seem to figure out.

Suppose I have this following code -

```py
class ClientThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self,ip,port,sock):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port
        self.sock = sock
        print (" New thread started for " + ip + ":"+str(port))

    def run(self):
        # do things

def Main_server():
    tcpsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    tcpsock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    tcpsock.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))

    threads = []

    while True: #Doubt_place
        tcpsock.listen(5)
        print ("Waiting for incoming connections...")

        (conn, (ip,port)) = tcpsock.accept()
        print ('Got connection from ', (ip,port))

        newthread = ClientThread(ip,port,conn)
        newthread.start()
        threads.append(newthread)

    for t in threads:
        t.join()
```

So in the `Main_server()` method - at first I am initiating socket object. Also creating a list(`threads`).

Then I am running an infinite loop where I am creating threads and calling `start()` which will invoke the `run()` method. So far this seems right. But after that I am trying to `join()` the created threads in the loop to make sure each thread completes their process.

My question is - **as I am running a infinite loop, It should run forever and the last for loop should never execute. how the `t.join()` block executes?**

I feel stupid not be able to figure out what's happening here. I would really appreciate if anyone can point me to a right direction whether with a specific answer or any documentation.

Comment: Are you sure the `for t in threads` loop is actually reached? It doesn't look like it ever will be.

Comment: Exactly!!! That's my doubt too. I can't seem to find the exact article where I found this.  But [this one](https://www.techbeamers.com/python-tutorial-write-multithreaded-python-server/) is pretty similar. Just take a look at the `Python-Server.Py` part in this article.

Comment: It won't be reached, unless/until you add some logic to break out of the infinite loop.  Presumably that code at the bottom is there so that if/when you do add some shutdown-logic to your server, you won't forget to add it (since waiting for child threads to exit is necessary to do a reliable shutdown)

Comment: @ArnabRoy That looks like a bad, broken example. I wouldn't trust that site. The code they're showing will never `join`.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Thanks!! Just to be sure - what would be the ideal way to join the threads here? Or as I am running an infinite loop here, the join is not necessary?

Comment: @ArnabRoy This example is a little contrived/overly simple to be able to say what the best way would be. You would have to decide what conditions should cause the listening loop to terminate. If this were a full UI program, you may want to join when the UI terminates, or the user decides to stop listening. In a console program, you may just want to listen for an interrupt exception or something.

Comment: It's been awhile since I've done threading in Python, so I can't remember if joining in necessary in every case. In Java, iirc, outstanding running threads are automatically terminated by the JVM (eventually) when the main thread terminates. I'm sure you can find info on the subject of you search.